# Change default color by group in simple R plot

Tags: r, plot, colors

I'm using a built-in R dataset. When I run the following code, the data in the plot are colored differently based on the variable month, which is what I want. How can I change the default colors (e.g., to: blue, orange, green, red, and pink)? I prefer not to do add a vector with color names after `col=`.

```
data("airquality")
plot(airquality$Ozone, col=airquality$Month)
```

Comment: `mypal <- rainbow(12); plot(airquality$Ozone, col=mypal[airquality$Month])`. Or see `?palette` (which isn't recommended).

Comment: Or,  if you don't like `rainbow`, the help page `?rainbow` lists several other palettes that you could try.